# Given a line segment and a point in 3D, how to find the normal of the segment towards the point?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 3D line $L$ defined by $p_1 (x, y, z)$ and $p_2(x, y, z)$ and a third point $p_3(x,y,z)$. How do I find a normal of $L$ that points towards $p_3$ (a general case)? How to do it when $p_3 = (0, 0, 0)$ (particular case)?

Answer (score 0):

First, work out an equation for the line with your first two points. Then note the general form of perpendiculars to that line. Then substitute the third point into the general form. This should (?) yield a second line equation but with some undefined terms. Then solve the simultaneous equations yielding the intersection point. Then with two points on the correct perpendicular you can work out an equation for that line as well.

If the third point is the origin the procedure would be the same with p3 = (0,0,0).